# want to block user agents with just a hypen at a apache level, not htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, block, agent

I am trying to block access to wp-login.php and xmlrpc.php for all sites on a web server. I want to do this at apache level, not htaccess.

I have a file in conf.d of apache with the following, but when do a CURL test it still shows the page.

```
<Files ~ "^(wp-login|xmlrpc)\.php">
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        SetEnvIf User-Agent - bad_user
        Deny from env=bad_user 
</Files>
```

anybody know what i have wrong?

Comment: Your configuration seems correct. What is the curl command that you are using? Try this `curl -I -H "User-Agent: -" domain.com/wp-login.php` This should return 403 forbidden.

Comment: @nidhi I was using curl -A "-" domain/wp-login.php . Still get 200 response. Same result with your curl command

Comment: The curl command that you are using is fine and the configuration is also correct. You can either place these lines in the file `httpd.conf` or in a `xxxxx.conf` file under the `directory conf.d`. Note, **the file's extension should be .conf.** Also, remember to restart apache for changes to take effect.

Comment: @nidhi OK, I tried the code on a brand new install and it half worked. On the original server I was using, there is control panel software, so I had to change the conf filename to have zzzz_ at the start of the name so it was the last to load, and that sorted it out on the main server. The only problem now is that any User Agent that has a - gets blocked, so will this work to match exactly? : `SetEnvIf User-Agent "^-$" bad_user`

Comment: Yes, you are right. `SetEnvIf User-Agent "^-$" bad_user` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @nidhi for the assistance. The answer here is to use the following in an apache conf.d file to be:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent "^-$" bad_user
SetEnvIf User-Agent "^$" bad_user
<Files ~ "^(wp-login|xmlrpc)\.php">
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Deny from env=bad_user
</Files>
```

The code will block any user agent that is blank or just a hyphen (-) that is trying to access wp-login.php or xmlrpc.php
make sure you name the file something like zzzz_blockua.conf so that apache loads it last.

This will help reduce the load on your server as bots hitting those pages don't take up php/mysql processes and apache just returns a 403 error.

It affects all sites on the server, so if you have a shared hosting server, you don't need to use htaccess for each site